# Запятая после "после"

Tags: пунктуация

> Гаджет не просто берет на себя процесс мышления, после(,) мы даже не можем найти обратную дорогу не полагаясь на GPS.

Нужна ли запятая в скобках в этом предложении? И если да, то по-какому принципу?

Что изменится если вместо "после" будет стоять "потом"?

Answer (score 1):

1) Я полагаю, что наречия ***потом*** и ***после*** не могут достаточно чётко обозначить смысловые отношения между предложениями.

**Вариант редактирования:**

Гаджет не просто берет на себя процесс мышления —  **в конечном результате (итоге)** мы даже не можем найти обратную дорогу, не полагаясь на GPS.

**Запятая** после наречного выражения ***в конечном результате*** не ставится. Между простыми предложениями в составе БСП лучше поставить **тире**, чтобы обозначить причинно-следственные отношения.

2) Гаджет не просто берет на себя процесс мышления, **потом** мы даже не можем найти обратную дорогу, не полагаясь на GPS.

Вариант с наречиями ***потом*** и ***после*** выглядит разговорным. В данном случае больше подходит наречие ***потом.*** Хотя они близки по значению, но семантические отличия между ними всё-таки есть.

ПОТОМ. I. местоим. нареч. 1. **Следуя за каким-л. событием, явлением, действием; затем.** Сперва поработаем, п. отдохнём. Часы пробили час, п. два. Сначала спой ты, а п. я. Как попасть к Адмиралтейству? Идите прямо, п. повернёте направо.

ПОСЛЕ. I. нареч. **Спустя некоторое время, позже, потом.** Он и п. мало изменился. П. поговорим. Одолжи денег, я п. отдам. П. расскажу. Сначала пойду я, а п. ты.

Comment: То есть по-вашему "потом", "после" не отделяются запятой по аналогии с "в конечном результате"?

Comment: Вообще это предложение из устной речи, поэтому для меня не стоит вопрос как лучше писать. Тем не менее "в конечном результате (итоге)" для меня звучит громоздко. Может быть просто "в результате" было бы лучше. Еще если "после" не отделять запятой, может быть не понятно к чему оно относится. Например "X, после Y" может быть интерпретировано как Y потом X. А в этом примере как раз таки X потом Y.

Comment: 1) Конечный результат - это последовательность результатов: "Гаджет не просто берет на себя процесс мышления, но и оказывает более существенное влияние на мозг человека, так что впоследствии мы даже не можем найти обратную дорогу, не полагаясь на GPS". Поэтому получается громоздко, но более точно. 2) В машинном языке свои правила, но в тексте запятая не ставится, смысл однозначно понятен. Что касается разговорности конструкции, то она связана именно с неточностью выражения. Точность для Вас важна?